# Is there a way to overwrite some data from the extended json config file in StyleDictionary?

Tags: javascript, json, style-dictionary

Question is simple:

I've a javascript file

```
const StyleDictionary = require('style-dictionary').extend('color-config.json');
```

and a json config file

```
{
  "source": ["tokens/color.json"],
  "platforms": {
    "css": {
      "transforms": ["color/css"],
```

Since I'm using a particular architecture, I need to prefix the source of all token config jsons with a pre path, so currently the situation is the following in my build process the *source* `tokens/color.json` is not working, instead I need to use for instance something like this `/extra/architecture/private/tokens/color.json`.
But I would like not to append this pre path in the json directly, I would like to be able to add it maybe via javascript through one single config parameter.

At the moment I couldn't find a good way to do it, only good approach is to edit directly the config json file.

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer, `extend` can be reworked multiple times, and returns the new updated object handler of Style Dictionary.

```
const StyleDictionary = require('style-dictionary').extend('color-config.json');

StyleDictionary.extend({
  source: StyleDictionary?.options?.source
    ? StyleDictionary.options.source.map(
        source => `extra/architecture/private/${source}`
      )
    : [],
  platforms: StyleDictionary.options.platforms,
}).buildAllPlatforms();
```